# Web Page: Certain image appears when I run locally, but disappears when displayed on the internet

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a simple web game, and I'm using a number of different sprites. When I run it in my browser locally, all the images appear like they should. However, when I ftp my project to the server and access it through the internet, two specific sprites out of the dozen others fail to appear. I don't understand why this happens, or why it's those two images. In my script, all my path names for the sources are relative to my index.html, so I can't see why that would be the problem. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this to happen?

EDIT: Here's some of my code for those specific images

```
var ImageSources = [
"jseco_tiles/fish_tiles/crab.png",
"jseco_tiles/Sturgeon/Sturgeon.png",
]

var fishImage = new Image();
fishImage.src = ImgSources[0];
fishImage.addEventListener('load', drawTile);

var sturgeonImage = new Image();
sturgeonImage.src = ImgSources[1];
sturgeonImage.addEventListener('load', drawTile);
```

I actually had a bunch of images created this way (that array is much bigger), which I know isn't a good idea, but regardless it all worked locally.

Comment: We would need more detailed information to be more helpful. Try to give us a chunk of code. My first advice is for you to check the names, they usually can be the cause of conflict with reserved words somehow.

Comment: Try to see the source code if the online version changed, and forbid your web browser cache may help.

Comment: okay, I've added some source code

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found out what was wrong. The way I was getting my app to draw those sprites was to only do it when so many images were preloaded. I guess putting it online caused images to load differently than when run locally? In hindsight, that was a pretty dumb idea since I only applied it to those two images, so I just removed that condition from my drawing routine. So, if anyone has a similar problem, you might want to check how your script is handling image loading.